# C++ delete operator without "new"

Tags: c++, class, delete-operator

Is it possible to use delete operator on class instance without new operator to deallocate memory? Like this:

```
Class myclass{public void hi{std::cout<<"hi\n";};}

myclass class1;
delete &class1;
class1.hi(); //results in error
```

Thanks

Comment: possible: yes, correct: no way. For every `new` there should be one `delete` and vice versa

Comment: Why do you think you need to do it?

Comment: I was just curious :D

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is explicitly stated in the standard of the language and in every C++ tutorial. Now you cannot do that. For most implementations that memory resides on the stack and cannot be freed nor would you be able to use it in a meaningful way. Read up on the stack and the heap (eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap) for a better understanding of the underlying mechanics, but keep in mind this is implementation detail and not the C++ language.

Comment: A slightly more interesting question is if you can call `delete` on a pointer that was previously allocated with `malloc` (not `new`)

Comment: @RPGillespie - It's exactly the same answer though

Comment: @RPGillespie: For me the only interesting question is what happens if you have something like `delete new foo[1];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the behaviour would be *undefined*.

You should only use `delete` on a pointer that's been given to you by `new`. The *type* of the pointer needs to be the same too, unless it points to an appropriate instance of a polymorphic class.

Comment: Then why does the program results in error on function call after delete operator and not on delete operator?

Comment: @Nick: That's one manifestation of undefined behaviour. Informally, you've probably completely rogered your stack.

Comment: Doesn't it mean that delete actually deletes the nonpointer type object 

Comment: @Nick: Maybe, maybe not. I don't think you're grasping what undefined behaviour means here.

Comment: No, undefined behavior means it does anything at all. It can vary across implementations, compiler versions and even different programs that use some common section of code. It might happen to do what you expected it to do but the behavior is absolutely volatile and cannot be relied on.

Comment: @Nick undefined means that it will vary from compiler to compiler. You might get one result with Visual Studio, and another result with GNU

Comment: @RPGillespie That's implementation-specific behavior.

Comment: I understand now what you mean

Comment: @Nick: Basically it means that the compiler could eat your cat. And I can't resist plugging the question I answered yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48623709/if-a-part-of-the-program-exhibits-undefined-behavior-would-it-affect-the-remain/48623785#48623785

Comment: @DeiDei I know, but I was giving a layman's example so it's easier for Op to understand. A lot of undefined behavior (according to the spec) is "defined" in specific implementations

Comment: Reference for the various types of behaviour: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: Thanks guys, i will definitely check out more info on undefined behavior